# system R command and shell output different

Tags: python, r, shell, anaconda

I have ubuntu's default python and Anaconda Python installed in my system. When I run system command in R:

```
> system('which python')
/usr/bin/python
```

However from shell:

```
user@user:~/Documents/Rad/jee/Solver$ which python
/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Also from Rscript command line mode:

```
user@user:~/Documents/Rad/jee/Solver$ Rscript -e "system('which python')"
/home/user/anaconda2/bin/python
```

What might be different in R system command to give different output.

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is different.

Comment: Thanks @OrtomalaLokni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I found the answer in the way Anaconda adds python executable path in PATH. Anaconda adds it in .bashrc which is only available in bash so I can see it when I did anything in my terminal. However it looks like R system command makes sh call. So anaconda python was not available in R system command output.

After moving anaconda setting from .bashrc to .profile file; problem got resolved.